# Some browser Mistake

Tags: html, css, mobile-browser

Hey guys I have some problem with browsers. I have a blogger site (soon buying my own domain). I am nerd in css etc can someone help me. The first browser is uc browser of android and second is google chrome

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uKJN.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjgzA.jpg

I want to make the first image look like the second one. the link is

perfectbloggertricks.blogspot.com

Can anyone help me with this ?

```
<header class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top main-top-nav' role='banner'>
<div class='container' style='background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #525252 5%, #262626 100%);border-top:2px        
solid #7562FF;box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #a8a8a8'>
<div class='navbar-header' style='height:50px;background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #525252 5%, #262626
100%);box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #a8a8a8'>
  <button class='navbar-toggle' data-target='.bs-navbar-collapse' data-toggle='collapse' type='button'>
    <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class='icon-bar'/>
    <span class='icon-bar'/>
    <span class='icon-bar'/>
  </button>
  <a class='myButton1' href='/' style='font-variant:small-caps;font-family:serif;font-size:19px;color:rgb(255,
  255, 255);line-height:24px;padding:12px 14px}'>Home</a>
  </div>
<nav class='collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse' role='navigation'>
  <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
    <li>
      <a class='myButton1' href='#'>Getting started</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class='myButton1' href='#'>Adsense</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class='myButton1' href='#'>Components</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class='myButton1' href='#'>JavaScript</a>
    </li>
    <li>
 <a class='myButton1' href='http://perfectbloggertricks.blogspot.com/search/label/Seo'>Seo</a>
 </li>
 <li>
      <a class='myButton1' href='#'>Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: please post your HTML and CSS....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two ways, either make `width` to `100%` or define explicit pixel values for `width` and `height` of the banner to make it work.

Comment: The Picture is being streched and asI said I am nerd in css. Can you describe hw to do that and also the navbar ? or can you just provide me the code that I can change ?

Comment: What Code ? Can you describe ?

Comment: where you have put your question, edit it and paste your HTML and CSS code.

Comment: I don't know how to put the code I have given the link in the post but there are no more links allowed hen two.